# how to show the first 20 count from 21 in ggplot rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code

```
#plot the graph
commont = n()) %>%
  top_n(n = (21), wt = count) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=r
```

but I don't want the top word ('br') to be in the plot.
can you help, please?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `slice` after the `top_n` to remove the first row

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
listings_words %>%
     group_by(word) %>%
     summarise(count = n()) %>%        
     top_n(n = (21), wt = count)  %>%
     arrange(desc(count)) %>%
     slice(-1) %>%
     droplevels() %>%
     ggplot() +
      geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=reorder(word, count),y=count),
       stat="identity", fill = "brown") +
     labs(title="Top 20 words described in listings",
           y="Word count", x="Most common Words") +
     coord_flip() +
     theme_minimal()
```

---

If there are ties for the top, then use `filter`

```
listings_words %>%
     group_by(word) %>%
     summarise(count = n()) %>%        
     top_n(n = (21), wt = count)  %>%
     arrange(desc(count)) %>%
     filter(count != max(count)) %>%
     droplevels() %>%
     ggplot() +
      geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=reorder(word, count),y=count),
       stat="identity", fill = "brown") +
     labs(title="Top 20 words described in listings",
           y="Word count", x="Most common Words") +
     coord_flip() +
     theme_minimal()
```